# Is it true $\left|\dfrac{1}{2^a}-\dfrac{1}{2^b}\right|<b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, absolute-value

Let $0 \leq a <b<1$ be two real numbers

Is it true that
$$
\left|
\dfrac
{1}
{2^a}
-
\dfrac
{1}
{2^b}
\right|
<b
$$

Comment: For fixed $b$, the left side is maximized when $a=0$ so you just need to show that $1-\frac{1}{2^b}<b.$ (No need for absolute values, either.)

Comment: This in turn means you need $2^b< \frac{1}{1-b}$ for $b\in(0,1)$

Comment: You can then use power series to prove this inequality, with $2^b=e^{b\log 2}$ with $\log 2<1$ so every term in the power series for $2^b$ (other than the constant term) has coefficient $<1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's true.

We need to prove that
$$b2^{a+b}+2^a-2^b>0$$ and since $2^a\geq1$, it's enough to prove that
$$b2^b+1-2^b>0$$ or $f(b)>0$, where
$$f(b)=b-1+2^{-b}.$$
Indeed, $$f'(b)=1-2^{-b}\ln2=\frac{2^b-\ln2}{2^b}>\frac{1-\ln2}{2^b}>0,$$
which says $$f(b)>f(0)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: thanks @Michael Rozenberg  for your answer

Comment: @Matey Math You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version $f(x)=\frac{1}{2^x}$. Using [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), $\exists c\in(a.b)$ s.t.
$$\left|f(a)-f(b)\right|=\left|f'(c)\right|\left|a-b\right|$$
Or
$$\left|\frac{1}{2^a}-\frac{1}{2^b}\right|=\left|-\frac{1}{2^c} \ln{2}\right|\left|a-b\right|<\left|\frac{1}{2^c} \right|\left|b-a\right|=\frac{1}{2^c} (b-a)\leq b-a<b$$

Comment: By far the simplest.

Comment: @rtybase simple and elegant proof

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $b$, the maximum of the left side is when $a=0$, so you want:

$$1-\frac{1}{2^b}<b$$

for $b\in(0,1)$. (The absolute values are unnecessary.)

This is equivalent to:

$$2^b\leq \frac{1}{1-b}
$$

for $b\in(0,1)$.

This can be seen by Taylor series:

$$2^b=e^{b\log 2}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^k 2}{k!}b^k$$

and
$$\frac{1}{1-b}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b^k$$

But $0<\log 2<1$ so $\frac{\log^k 2}{k!}<\frac{1}{k!}\leq 1$ and thus $$2^b<\frac{1}{1-b}$$

Answer (score 1):

As others have observed, it's enough to show that $1-{1\over2^b}\lt b$ for $b\gt0$.  We'll show a stronger inequality.

Since $b\ge0$, we have

$${1\over 2^{bx}}=e^{-(b\ln2)x}\lt1$$

for $0\lt x$, and thus

$$1\gt\int_0^1e^{-(b\ln 2)x}dx={1\over b\ln2}{1\over2^{bx}}\Big|_1^0={1\over b\ln2}\left(1-{1\over2^b}\right)$$

which, since $0\lt\ln2\lt1$, gives us the stronger inequality

$$1-{1\over2^b}\lt b\ln2\quad\text{for }b\gt0$$

Comment: thanks @Barry Cipra